# Cocos2D iPhone llvm problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, llvm

I am using newest Xcode(4.6.3) and I have a big problem with my iPhone game application.
Game is made with Cocos2D for iPhone (2.1). When I am running the game it crashes sometimes with errors like LLVM::something, that (I believe) have CCSprite background.
And now I had an SIGABRT with an one line output to my console: 
**UNREACHABLE executed!**

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #6: tid = 0x2503, 0x99f92a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x99f92a6a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x93e42b2f libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_kill + 101
    frame #2: 0x03acc5eb libLLVMContainer.dylib`abort + 27
    frame #3: 0x03abbcc5 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::llvm_unreachable_internal(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 485
    frame #4: 0x03a49922 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::ValueHandleBase::ValueIsDeleted(llvm::Value*) + 578
    frame #5: 0x03a496a7 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::Value::~Value() + 39
    frame #6: 0x03a24cb1 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::BinaryOperator::~BinaryOperator() + 17
    frame #7: 0x037e2c4e libLLVMContainer.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::LSRInstance::LSRInstance(llvm::TargetLowering const*, llvm::Loop*, llvm::Pass*) + 28830
    frame #8: 0x037db8f7 libLLVMContainer.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::LoopStrengthReduce::runOnLoop(llvm::Loop*, llvm::LPPassManager&) + 39
    frame #9: 0x03913148 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::LPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 936
    frame #10: 0x03a3767c libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 284
    frame #11: 0x03a37036 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Function&) + 198
    frame #12: 0x03a36f3a libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::FunctionPassManager::run(llvm::Function&) + 122
    frame #13: 0x0341d982 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::JIT::getPointerToFunction(llvm::Function*) + 338
    frame #14: 0x03392589 libCoreVMClient.dylib`cvmsCompBuildMonolithicFunction + 1614
    frame #15: 0x033952c0 libCoreVMClient.dylib`cvmsServerBuildMonolithicFunction + 235
    frame #16: 0x03393b22 libCoreVMClient.dylib`CVMSBuildMonolithicFunction + 99
    frame #17: 0x0338aeea libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib`cvm_deferred_build_monolithic(void*) + 148
    frame #18: 0x0338a5e0 libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib`cvmDoWork + 57
    frame #19: 0x93e415b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344
```

This problem occurs very often, about 3 times for 10 runs.
Maybe you guys know that problem and what causes it?
I am giving images from stacks on some threads to give bigger picture of this problem.
[image: thread 6]

[image: Main thread]

There is one more error that occurs very often: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It has the same backround ([CCSprite draw]). 
backtrace:

```
    (lldb) bt 
* thread #6: tid = 0x2503, 0x03a40f6b libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::PointerType::get(llvm::Type const*, unsigned int) + 27, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xc)
    frame #0: 0x03a40f6b libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::PointerType::get(llvm::Type const*, unsigned int) + 27
    frame #1: 0x033bdab4 libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::GetElementPtrInst::GetElementPtrInst<llvm::Value**>(llvm::Value*, llvm::Value**, llvm::Value**, unsigned int, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Instruction*) + 132
    frame #2: 0x0341106c libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::BitcodeReader::ParseFunctionBody(llvm::Function*) + 3292
    frame #3: 0x034153ad libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::BitcodeReader::Materialize(llvm::GlobalValue*, std::string*) + 381
    frame #4: 0x03a3060b libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::Module::Materialize(llvm::GlobalValue*, std::string*) + 43
    frame #5: 0x03a0bbaf libLLVMContainer.dylib`llvm::GlobalValue::Materialize(std::string*) + 31
    frame #6: 0x0eef0f47 libGLVMPlugin.dylib`cvmLookupModularFunction + 72
    frame #7: 0x0ef2e288 libGLVMPlugin.dylib`glvmBuildFPTransformFunction + 424
    frame #8: 0x0ef416da libGLVMPlugin.dylib`cvmsModularBuilder + 166
    frame #9: 0x0339278d libCoreVMClient.dylib`cvmsCompBuildModularFunction + 179
    frame #10: 0x033956bf libCoreVMClient.dylib`cvmsServerBuildModularFunction + 245
    frame #11: 0x03393bcf libCoreVMClient.dylib`CVMSBuildModularFunction + 112
    frame #12: 0x0338a78f libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib`cvm_deferred_build_modular(void*) + 247
    frame #13: 0x0338a5e0 libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib`cvmDoWork + 57
    frame #14: 0x93e415b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344
```

Another EXC_BAD_ACCESS from LLVM runtime code:
[image: SelectionDAG llvm instruction]

When I suspend thread 6, everything is just fine and no crashes.. but the FPS rate drops by a half. I Don't have any ideas what is the source of a problem. I have check my memory leaks nad repaired them, even if they were small (for example few bytes in a 5 min application run). I have cut down my source code to some basics, but it did not help. Crashes still exists. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: http://nondot.org/sabre/LLVMNotes/UnreachableInstruction.txt

Comment: enable exception breakpoint in Xcode, that may help to show the offending code. If not, reduce your code to a minimum until the error goes away, then you can home in on the cause of the crashes.

Comment: I have been testing my app since yesterday in every possible way. Is that possible that something is wrong with my enviroment? Now I got error from some LLVM internal call and it came from NSLog() with a healthy string. It's just weird behavior.

Comment: And another LLVM runtime error EXC_BAD_ACCESS on some registers eax/ecx. llvm::SelectionDAG::getNode(); I can't even see where is the origin of a problem, because it sometimes come out in a runtime in ios runtime loops/event handling.

Comment: reinstalling the environment did not give any positive result. still the same..

Comment: @iPatel your link is not relevant to this question as it is about the [LLVM IR `unreachable` instruction](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#unreachable-instruction), while the question involves the [`llvm_unreachable` C++ macro](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ErrorHandling_8h.html#ace243f5c25697a1107cce46626b3dc94) used in the LLVM source code.